# Go to test website status (ping)

Tags: http, go, ping

Is there any other better way to ping websites and check if the website is available or not?

I just need to get the status code not get(download) all websites...

```
func Ping(domain string) int {
    timeout := time.Duration(2 * time.Second)
    dialTimeout := func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return net.DialTimeout(network, addr, timeout)
    }
    transport := http.Transport{
        Dial: dialTimeout,
    }
    client := http.Client{
        Transport: &transport,
    }
    url := "http://" + domain
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    return resp.StatusCode
}
```

This function is too slow and when I run with goroutines, it goes over the limits and gives me the errors...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use a single transport. Because the transport maintains a pool of connections, you should not create and ignore transports willy nilly.
- Close the response body as described at the beginning of the [net/http doc](http://godoc.org/net/http).
- Use HEAD if you are only interested in the status.
- Check errors.

Code:

```
var client = http.Client{
  Transport: &http.Transport{
    Dial: net.Dialer{Timeout: 2 * time.Second}.Dial,
  },
}

func Ping(domain string) (int, error) {
    url := "http://" + domain
    req, err := http.NewRequest("HEAD", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
       return 0, err
    }
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
       return 0, err
    }
    resp.Body.Close()
    return resp.StatusCode, nil
}
```

Comment: I think the success return should be `return resp.StatusCode, nil`

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the top result on Google for Pinging in Go, just know there have been several packages written for this purpose, but if you plan to use this answer, I had to make some changes for this to work.

```
import (
   "time"
   "net/http"
)

var client = http.Client{
   Timeout: 2 * time.Second,
}
```

But otherwise keeping the same with the accepted answer.

But I'm a beginner in Go so there may be a better way to do this.